# Running javacode with MySQL connectivity does not fetch proper results

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Iam new to java and I wrote Below code to fetch from MySql Workbench table  using Java code:

```
           package Filereader;
           import java.sql.*;

               public class DBConnection {

             public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;

    try
    {   
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
    con  = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world","root","password"); 
    st = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "select * from city where id = 1;";
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next())
    {
        int id = rs.getInt("ID");
        String Name = rs.getString("Name");
        String CountryCode = rs.getString("CountryCode");
        String District = rs.getString("District");
        int Population = rs.getInt("Population");           
        System.out.println(id);
        System.out.println(Name);
        System.out.println(CountryCode);
        System.out.println(District);
        System.out.println(Population);         
    }
    rs.close();
    st.close();
    con.close();    
}catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();        
}finally
{
    try{
         if(st!=null)
            st.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }
      try{
         if(con!=null)
            con.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
```

}

On Running it, connection is made but results are not fetched properly. Only 1st row is fetched with first column missing.

Logs/Statements seen:

```
 Sat Mar 28 21:34:36 IST 2015 TRACE: <--  Buffer.java:292         com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer.readInt(..) returning 2
 Sat Mar 28 21:34:36 IST 2015 TRACE: <--  MysqlIO.java:2247 com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readServerStatusForResultSets(..) returning null
 Sat Mar 28 21:34:36 IST 2015 TRACE: --> Connection.java:5895 com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.versionMeetsMinimum(5, 0, 2)
 Sat Mar 28 21:34:36 IST 2015 TRACE: --> Connection.java:1903 com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.checkClosed()
```

....and so on

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't think semicolon is allowed in the actual sql string  `"select * from city where id = 1"`

Comment: Removed semicolon, still not much improvement in results

Comment: It will give you only one column because of `id = 1` and regarding missing column can you show the o/p you are getting?